# Find an old static IP address on a mac backup?

Tags: mac, backup, ip-address

I have an old backup of a mac via time machine, and I was wondering if there is some sort of accessible file that would have the static IP of the old computer it was backed up from.

If you are curious, I am in IT and it is a PITA to get a new static IP here.  I am just trying to use the old one to save some hassle.

I've tried searching through the system log with no success (but I might be doing it wrong- grep with a regexp for an IP).

Thanks!

Comment: What’s the grep command you’re using?

Answer (score 1):

The information is stored in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration` in these files:

```
com.apple.network.identification.plist
com.apple.preferences.plist
```